# ssh client with paramiko

Tags: python, multithreading, ssh, paramiko

```
import paramiko
import os

def connection():
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    privatekey = os.path.expanduser('/home/rabia/private')
    mkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(privatekey)
    ssh.connect('78.46.172.47', port=22, username='s0urd', password=None, pkey=mkey)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls')
    print stdout.readlines()

connection()
```

How can I make it so that one thread is waiting for a user input and the other is doing the ssh connection?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, then you should add something like this to your code:

```
import threading

_paramikoThread = threading.Thread(target=doParamikoConnection)
_paramikoThread.start()
# The following code is executed by parent thread.
_ans = ""
while _ans != "nay":
    _ans = raw_input("Should I loop again? [yay/nay]")
# Now we've ended user I/O session, wait for connection to complete.
_paramikoThread.join()
# At this point we have data collected from user and connection being initialised.
```